# Activity and AlertDialog are being launched twice

Tags: java, android

I have that `AlertDialog` that is showing twice, and I have no clue why! The problem doesn't apply only for `AlertDialogs`; However, it applies for `"Activities"` as well.

Note that i'm facing the problem with Android 4.0.3.However, When I run the application on Android 2.3.6, everything works normally.

In order to solve my problem with `Activitie`s, I have set in the manifest file :
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and it worked.

However, this cannot be done for `AlertDialog`s as they do not have any references in the manifest file to set it to `singleInstance` or something like that.

Some people told me to put a `BreakPoint` in order to check my code after `show()`. But I do not know how to put a `BreakPoint` and how to check.

EDIT:

I am using HoloEverywhere and SherlockActionBar. I do not know how much effect they do have.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.action_one:
        alertDialog();
        break;
    case R.id.action_two:
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Info.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);    
        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void alertDialog(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("My title");
        AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
        alert.show();

}
```

in `case R.id.action_two` it's working fine after setting the `launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest file. However, in `case R.id.action_one` which launches the `AlertDialog` it's still opening twice.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_options, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Can you also post your `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu`?

Comment: @Tushar also posted. But I don't think the problem is from the `AlertDialog`. As it also applies for `Activities` if `launchMode` is not set to `singleInstance`

Comment: it shouldn't be launching Activities twice with a single click either, regardless of `singleInstance` or not. Do you set a `MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener` anywhere?

Comment: one moment i'll try to make a button and test it on a button first to check if the problem is from the `menu`

Comment: With the Button it worked! So the problem resides somewhere with the optionsmenu...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27518/discussion-between-tushar-and-jonathan-hugh)

Comment: @Tushar IT WORKED! I changed `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` to `return true;` I don't know the reason.. but i just did it.. why do you think???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

to:

```
return true;
```

When you call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu`, it attaches additional `onMenuItemClickListener` listeners to each item in the menu, so that would cause 2 clicks to be recorded.

(PS: I actually figured this out and was going to post it, but had to take a call. No joke)

Comment: @JonathanHugh Sorry about not being able to give you the answer before, but I think it's better you independently discovered it anyways. Good luck with your app!